# how to change PATH vars on my iPhone console?

Tags: iphone, shell, path

I installed a terminal i my iPhone and I'm trying to install some utilities on it. To achieve it the only thing I have left is to change the order of the PATH variables on the system but I cannot find the place where they're stored.

When I write $PATH I get

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games
```

I need to edit the path so the /usr/bin appears before of /usr/local/bin.

I've read sites where they tell me to edit ~/.bashrc, ~/.cshrc, ~/.profile or /etc/paths but none of them exist on my system (in fact in ~ there's just .bash_history and some unimportant directories)

I access to my iPhone (iOS 4.2.1) through ssh from a Leopard MacBook

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question. Try superuser.com instead.

Comment: In fact this was originally a programming question. It was about installing a Phython module (PIL btw) to make a script to scale a picture, and one thing led me to another

Comment: @Jonathan Please don't suggest a site where this question is clearly off topic. It only encourages people to cross post and causes confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Which would be why I voted to close it and send it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `.bashrc` doesn't exist, you should be able to create it and set it in there:

```
PATH=$PATH:/extra/path/here:/other/path/here
export PATH
```

It would appear that you are indeed using bash as your shell since you have a `.bash_history`, but if you are using a separate shell it could be a separate file.

Comment: Thank you Daniel but the thing is that I need to edit the existing PATH vars not adding a new one, so the export command is a no go.